# Generate random enum without consecutive repetition

Tags: c++, random

How do I generate random enum values without consecutive repetition?

```
enum keycode {
    VK_LEFT   = 75,
    VK_UP     = 72,
    VK_RIGHT  = 77,
    VK_DOWN   = 80
};
```

VK_LEFT, VK_DOWN, VK_UP, VK_RIGHT, VK_DOWN ...

and not

VK_LEFT, VK_DOWN, **VK_UP**, **VK_UP**, VK_RIGHT ...

Comment: The simplest, although not necessarily most efficient way, is to generate all possible values in a vector, random shuffle it, and then truncate it to the desired number of values.

Comment: What is the purpose of the randomness? What do you mean by random?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your four values are 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Pick a random number N0 in {0, 1, 2, 3}.
Pick a random number N1 in {0, 1, 2, 3} \ {N0}.
Pick a random number N2 in {0, 1, 2, 3} \ {N1}.
Pick a random number N3 in {0, 1, 2, 3} \ {N2}.
And so on...

Answer (score 0):

When you call the code that generates the random value from your `enum`, have it check the new random value against the last value selected. If they're equal, select another value.

This could be done in a while loop. Pseudocode:

```
keycode value;
while (value != lastChosen)
    value = keycode[random.next];
lastChosen = value;
```

where `lastChosen` is the last selected value.

Comment: What if it's the same as a value picked 2 times ago?

Comment: The OP made no mention of having to iterate through all options before selecting the next value, only that two consecutive values cannot be the same.

Answer (score 0):

this will generate K non-repeating numbers between 1 and N:

```
vector<int> non_repeat(int K, int N)
{
    vector<int> res;
    int last = 1 + rand() % N;
    res.push_back(last);
    for(int i=1;i<K;++i)
    {
        int r = 1 + rand() % (N-1);
        if(r>=last) ++r;
        res.push_back(r);
        last = r;
    }
    return res;
}
```

should be fairly easy to adopt to your need